# Extracting elements from List in R

Tags: r, list, subscript

I am a beginner in R. So I am experimenting with lists to understand R. 
 `x <- list(foo = 1:4, bar = 0.6)` 
I am able to get the foo variable from x with `y = x[1]`. `x` and `y` both are lists and I can get the first element from `x` with `x[1]` but it is not possible to get the first element from `y` with `y[1]`. `y[1]` is giving 
*$foo
[1] 1 2 3 4*
What are the differences between `x` and `y` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R` can be confusing in this regard. The problem is that `x[1]` gives you a list, not the values stored in the first element of the list.

Suppose `x <- list(foo = 1:4, bar = 0.6)`, you can extract from x in two ways

You can subset by the index:
`x[[1]]` will give you the values in the first vector while `x[1]` will give you a list containing the first list in `x`

```
> x[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

> x[1]
$foo
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Beside `x[[1]]`, you can subset `x` by the name that you assigned, namely,

```
> x$foo
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

The reason `y = x[1]` doesn't work is because you're not assigning the vector of values 1 to 4 to `y`, you're passing a list. so `y` is a list of length 1. Consequently, you wish to do

```
y=x[[1]]
```

or

```
y=x$foo
```

This way, you can subset `y` as you desire:

```
> y[1]
[1] 1
```

HOWEVER, with you current method `y = x[1]`, `y` is a list, therefore, you can subset the `y` like you would a normal list:

```
> y[[1]][1]
[1] 1
```

or

```
> y$foo[1]
[1] 1
```